# Upload PDF from IOS App

Tags: ios, file-upload

I have an app which allows the user to upload PDF files which works fine in Android. I need the same capability in IOS as well, but I have seen that this is not directly supported by IOS. The PDF could lie as part of attachments in emails, and the user might have saved on the phone, need a way to retrieve all PDFs in phone and list it.

Has anyone implemented a similar feature in their apps? Is it feasible?

Comment: The file must be in your app bundle, I don't think that you can reach all pdf file on the device unless it's a jailbroken.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unable to find this explicitly documented somewhere. Do you have any reference

Comment: Sure, check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)